# Reverse time integration in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

Is there any workaround to force LTspice integrate backward in time from the \$t_0\$ to \$-t\$, for some \$t_0,t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}\$?

Comment: Are you, perchance, seeking to implement a convolution integral? If yes then you can simply use an input signal and an appropriately modelled kernel (filter) and simply run the simulation. If not, [what is it for](https://xyproblem.info/#)?

Comment: No, nothing like this. My aim is to check how the system evolves toward unstable invariant manifold \$\mathcal{W}_\mathrm{u}\$ as time \$t\rightarrow -\infty\$. It is worth mentioning that I already used some robust integration schemes in Matlab but time reversal failed terribly.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid I have some bad news... at least as far as LTspice (and SPICE, in general) is concerned.

Comment: If the problem space is LTI, then simply inverting the poles/zeros does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible directly. You could change your circuit to make +t *emulate* -t by using negative components or controlled sources etc. However this is likely going to be difficult to achieve convergence.

For instance, a capacitor has i=C.dV/dt; You could use a negative value of capacitance C (SPICE allows this !), to emulate the behaviour of a *positive* capacitance in the -t direction.

Comment: this sounds really clever, thank you I will give it a serious try